Проблема с установкой Jupyter через Termux в Android
У меня проблема с установкой Jupyter через Termux в Android. После установки Python пытаюсь поставить Jupyter и постоянно вылетает ошибка, пробовал и через виртуальное окружение
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
            error: subprocess-exited-with-error

            × pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
            │ exit code: 2
            ╰─> See above for output.

            note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
            [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error

      × pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> See above for output.

      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


Там везде написано "смотри выше", а выше вы всё отрезали.

Не осталось к сожалению полного ответа. Теперь получилось установить через виртуальное окружение и установив rust, но опять ошибка ImportError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "PyExc_ImportError" referenced by "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/my_project/env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/_zmq.cpython-312.so"...

Кстати ставил Jupyter lite, он запускается, но он никак не находит kernel. Ставил на termux Ubuntu, затем стандартный Jupyter, он также запускается, но не находит kernel. Что за жесть(((((((((

Обновите, пожалуйста, вопрос с учетом новых обстоятельств, упомянутых вами в комментариях.
